# Отдельная сортировка каждого столбца таблицы - List.Sort()

Tags: c#, winforms, сортировка, list, linq

Имеется `DataGridView` привязанный к `BindingSource`, который берет данные от `List<T>`. Данные разделены на страницы. Поэтому количество элементов в `List<T>` фиксировано (15 элементов). Элементом `T` является свой класс `ContractTableRow`.

Нажатие по заголовку столбца вызывает метод `DgvContract_ColumnHeaderMouseClick()`. Его задача на основе выбранного столбца сделать сортировку `List<T>` и вызвать повторное считывание данных `BindingSource.ResetBindings(false)`.

Сортировка должна происходить как обычно бывает: первый клик сортировка по возрастанию, второй клик по убыванию. Реализация на основе `List.Sort()` ([источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3309292/11563179))

```
objListOrder.Sort((x, y) => x.OrderDate.CompareTo(y.OrderDate));
```

Первое усложнение заключается в направлении сортировки. Код отличается только порядком `(x, y)` и `(y, x)`.

Второе усложнение из-за типа данных. Текущая реализация такова, что свойство по которому будет идти сортировка подставляется на ходу. Если не выполнить приведение к `string`, метод `CompareTo()` не доступен.

```
list.Sort((y, x) => ((string)x.GetType().GetProperty(col).GetValue(x))
                    .CompareTo(y.GetType().GetProperty(col).GetValue(y)));
```

Из-за этого выпадает одно свойство класса `ContractTableRow` - `float Salary`. Отсюда ветвление специально для него. Текущая реализация работает верно. Но ветвления и повторы кода заставляют задуматься.

```
public class ContractTableRow
{
    public int IdContract { get; set; } // не доступен для сортировки
    public string Num { get; set; }
    public string DateConclusion { get; set; }
    public string DateStartWork { get; set; }
    public string DateEndWork { get; set; }
    public float Salary { get; set; }
}

private void DgvContract_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    string col = dgvContract.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
    List<ContractTableRow> list = (List<ContractTableRow>)Source.DataSource;

    if (Source.Sort == col)
    {
        if (col == "Salary")
        {
            list.Sort((y, x) => x.Salary
                .CompareTo(y.GetType().GetProperty(col).GetValue(y)));
        }
        else
        {
            list.Sort((y, x) => ((string)x.GetType().GetProperty(col).GetValue(x))
                .CompareTo(y.GetType().GetProperty(col).GetValue(y)));
        }

        Source.Sort = null;
    }
    else
    {
        if (col == "Salary")
        {
            list.Sort((x, y) => x.Salary
                .CompareTo(y.GetType().GetProperty(col).GetValue(y)));
        }
        else
        {
            list.Sort((x, y) => ((string)x.GetType().GetProperty(col).GetValue(x))
                .CompareTo(y.GetType().GetProperty(col).GetValue(y)));
        }

        Source.Sort = col;
    }

    Source.ResetBindings(false);
}
```

Comment: А почему не работает сортировка по-умолчанию? Или чем она не устраивает

Comment: @defaultlocale Сортировка по умолчанию не работает. Клики по шапке не дают ничего. А вызов `DataGridView.Sort()` вызывает исключение `Элемент управления DataGridView нельзя упорядочить, если он привязан к IBindingList, не поддерживающему сортировку.`. Она бы устроила, если работала и числа не как строки сортировала.

Comment: `float Salary` - чтоб вам зарплату рассчитывали во float... (Хотя может получиться и выгода, да).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `Access` не хочет принимать `decimal`, выкидывает исключение `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`. Уже все варианты его чисел перебрал, ничего не берет.

Comment: Вообще, на эту тему вполне можно задать отдельный вопрос. Но можете сперва посмотреть [OLE DB Data Type Mappings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ole-db-data-type-mappings). Я в типах Access не разбираюсь, но так понимаю, должно быть `adCurrency DBTYPE_CY Decimal`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я не знаю как применять данный источник, создал новый [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1003560/Как-добавить-decimal-в-базу-данных-access-через-ef-core)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Первое усложнение заключается в направлении сортировки. Код отличается только порядком (x, y) и (y, x).

Не знаю как избежать ветвления, но можно его как можно более локализовать. Для этого можно объявить переменную для порядка сортировки:

```
var sortOrder = sort == col ? SortOrder.Descending : SortOrder.Ascending;
```

и использовать ее в лямбде, либо по условию вызывать `List.Reverse`. Манипуляции с `Source.Sort` также выполнять отдельно от сортировки.

> Второе усложнение из-за типа данных. Текущая реализация такова, что свойство по которому будет идти сортировка подставляется на ходу. Если не выполнить приведение к string, метод CompareTo() не доступен.

[`CompareTo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable.compareto?view=netframework-4.8#System_IComparable_CompareTo_System_Object_) определен в интерфейсе `IComparable`, т.ч. вместо `string` можно использовать интерфейс.

Кроме этого можно вынести обращение к свойству за пределы лямбды, т.к. класс всегда один и тот же `ContractTableRow`. В результате получим что-то вроде:

```
private void DgvContract_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    string col = dgvContract.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
    List<ContractTableRow> list = (List<ContractTableRow>)Source.DataSource;
    var sortOrder = Source.Sort == col ? SortOrder.Descending : SortOrder.Ascending;
    var propertyInfo = typeof(ContractTableRow).GetProperty(col);
    list.Sort((x, y) =>
         {
              //меняем параметры местами в зависимости от сортировки
              var first = sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ? x : y;
              var second = sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ? y : x;
              var firstValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(first);
              var secondValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(second);
              //сравниваем через IComparable
              return ((IComparable) firstValue).CompareTo(secondValue);
         });
    Source.Sort = Source.Sort == col ? null : col;
    Source.ResetBindings(false);
}
```

Comment: Потеряли строчку присвоения `list`. Замерил `Stopwatch`, оба варианта работают за `0.16 - 0.17` на моем компьютере. Код аккуратнее, время тоже.

Comment: @Owl Исправил, спасибо. Кстати, в качестве альтернативы, посмотрите на [BindingListView](http://blw.sourceforge.net/). Есть пример на en.SO: [How do I implement automatic sorting of DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4217210). С ним получится привязать список к гриду и получить автоматическую сортировку.

Answer (score 0):

Сортировка колонки в DataGridView с DataSource. Дополнительно устанавливаем и сбрасываем SortGlyphDirection

```
private void ItemsTable_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    var sortingColumn = ItemsTable.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];

    var propertyInfo = typeof(ListingInfo).GetProperty(sortingColumn.DataPropertyName);
    if (propertyInfo == null) // ignore columns with buttons or pictures
        return;

    foreach (DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn in ItemsTable.Columns)
    {
        if (dataGridViewColumn != sortingColumn)
            dataGridViewColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.None;
    }
    sortingColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = sortingColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection == SortOrder.Ascending
        ? SortOrder.Descending : SortOrder.Ascending;

    _listingsList.Sort((x, y) =>
    {
        var first = sortingColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection == SortOrder.Ascending ? x : y;
        var second = sortingColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection == SortOrder.Ascending ? y : x;
        var firstValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(first);
        var secondValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(second);
        if (firstValue == null)
            return secondValue == null ? 0 : -1;
        return secondValue == null ? 1 : ((IComparable)firstValue).CompareTo(secondValue);
    });

    // tell the binding list to raise a list change event so that bound controls reflect the new item order
    ItemsTable.ResetBindings();
    ItemsTable.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]