# Как добавить decimal в базу данных Access через EF Core?

Tags: c#, ms-access, entity-framework-core

Имем сущность `Contracts` со свойством `Salary`. Добавление в базу с помощью метода `Add()`. Изначально `Salary` был типом `float`, модель и сущности были сгенерированы провайдером `Jet` (он используется для `Access`).

Разбирая другие свои вопросы, мне несколько раз указывали на то, что `Salary`, то есть `Зарплату` необходимо держать в `decimal`. Я исправил тип и все связанные с этим участки кода (это переводы из текста и обратно, когда значение уходит в контрол и из него).

Поле `Salary` в базе данных исправлял на (в самом `Access` через `GUI`) `Денежный`, `Одинарное с плавающей точной`, `Двойное с плавающей точной`, `Действительные`. Если `Salary` в коде будет `decimal` без дробной части, добавление пройдет успешно. Когда там будет дробная часть, падает исключение:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Когда `Salary` в коде `float` или `double`, добавление корректно и с дробной частью, и без.

Перевод из текста пробовал и через `decimal.Parse()`, и через `Convert.ToDecimal()`

Отсюда вопрос, как добавить `decimal` в `Access`? К слову, вся математика над данным полем описывается свойством `SalaryWithTax`

```
public partial class Contracts
{
    ...
    //public double Salary { get; set; }
    //public float Salary { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    ...
}

static public bool Add(object obj)
{
    bool result = true;
    try
    {
        using (ModelContext context = new ModelContext())
        {
            context.Add(obj);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { ... }

    return result;
}

// в данный момент все указанные переменные в double
public double SalaryWithTax
{
    get { return salaryWithTax; }
    set
    {
        salaryWithTax = value;
        incomeTaxValue = (salaryWithTax * incomeTaxProcent) / 100;
        insuranceTaxValue = (salaryWithTax * insuranceTaxProcent) / 100;
        Salary = salaryWithTax - incomeTaxValue - insuranceTaxValue;
    }
}
```

**Update**

Поставил тип `Действительное` для `Salary` в базе данных и пересоздал модель через провайдера `Jet`. `Salary` сущности `Contracts` получило тип `decimal`. В `OnModelCreating()` добавилось `.HasColumnType("decimal(18, 2)")`. Но по прежнему тоже исключение при добавлении числа с дробью. По дебагу видно, что `Parse()` или `Convert()` делают нормальное число. `Access 2016`, база `.accdb`

**Update 2**

Я создал новую базу данных `Access` с таблицей `Table` (`int id` и`decimal salary`). Модель создана провайдером `Jet`:

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=nameDB.accdb;" -Provider EntityFrameworkCore.Jet
```

И консольную программу с таким `Main()`:

```
using(ModelContext context = new ModelContext())
{
    decimal x = 17.45M;
    Table table = new Table();
    table.Id = 1;
    table.Salary = x;
    context.Table.Add(table);
    context.SaveChanges(); // исключение падает тут
}
```

Получаю тоже самое исключение. Приведу полный текст:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: "An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."
>
> OleDbException: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Код `OnConfiguring()` создался такой. Я пробовал менять строку `.HasColumnType("decimal(18, 0)")` на `18, 2` (в базе тоже) - никак не влияет, тоже самое исключение.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.2.6-servicing-10079");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Table>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("table");

        entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");

        entity.Property(e => e.Salary)
            .HasColumnName("salary")
            .HasColumnType("decimal(18, 0)")
            .HasDefaultValueSql("0");
    });
}
```

[Ссылка](https://yadi.sk/d/TerwZw6c6OhPUQ) на скачивание консольной программы.

Comment: Я в своей финансовой программе пользуюсь decimal и EF core без проблем из коробки ну разве точность [указываю](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43277154/5752652) как 18,2. Возможно, ваши проблемы не с EF core связаны а с тем, что у вас выставлен не тот разделитель / выставлена не та культура? что-то типа: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7570848/5752652 а вот тут вообще пишут, что в акцесс 2007 децимал кривой: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9787003/5752652

Comment: @AK какой тип у вас выбран в самом Access для decimal?

Comment: У меня не Access, у меня asp.net + EFcore, поэтому я и рекомендовал не к общей с нами части (EF) присмотреться, а к тому, что у нас разное.

Comment: @AK я попробовал и 18.2, и культуру. Исключение тоже самое.